# How to specify the order results with a SQL UNION?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-order-by, union

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
select * from (select * from customquestionbank where questionid=6 or secondquestionid=6 
union select * from customquestionbank where questionid=5 or secondquestionid=5 
union select * from customquestionbank where questionid=10 or secondquestionid=10 
union select * from customquestionbank where questionid=11 or secondquestionid=11) Tabled
```

Being new to this site I cannot post images yet, but here is what the result look like:

```
questionid -> 5,6 ,10,11
```

However, I want the result to be displayed in the same order as my select statements above. In other words, questionid=6 returned first, then 5, and so on.

Comment: And what additional columns are in `customquestionbank` (apart from `questionid` and `secondquestionid`?)

Comment: If you have two records with `(questionid, secondquestionid)` = `(5, 6)` and `(6, 5)`, accordingly, how shall they be sorted?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all the unions, just make it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM   customquestionbank 
WHERE  questionid IN ( 6, 5, 10, 11 ) 
        OR secondquestionid IN ( 6, 5, 10, 11 ) 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN 6 IN ( questionid, secondquestionid ) THEN 0 
            WHEN 5 IN ( questionid, secondquestionid ) THEN 1 
            WHEN 10 IN ( questionid, secondquestionid ) THEN 2 
            WHEN 11 IN ( questionid, secondquestionid ) THEN 3 
          END
```

Comment: The `order by` doesn't take account that it might be the `secondquestionid` that matched (for values other than `6`)

Comment: @MartinSmith possibly like this.

Comment: Still not correct. If the `questionid` doesn't match any of the values then the `secondquestionid` should be used for sorting. At the moment you will prioritise the non matching `questionid` in ordering. e.g. a row with `(100,5)` will get sorted after `(11,2)` which is not the desired result.

Comment: @MartinSmith true that, how do you propose to order? Do you think it's possible without group by?

Comment: Could use `ORDER BY CASE WHEN 6 IN (questionid, secondquestionid) THEN 0 WHEN 5 IN (questionid, secondquestionid) THEN 1  WHEN 10 IN (questionid, secondquestionid) THEN 2 /*etc*/ END`

Comment: @MartinSmith I dind't know that was possible. I'm more of a sybase guy. Edit done!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the super select that you are using

Write the query as

```
Select * from query1 union
Select * from query2 union
Select * from query3;
```

This will bring your result as needed

Else try this

```
Select col1,col2 from( Select 1,q1.* from query1 q1 union
Select 2,q2.* from query2 q2 union
Select 3,q1.* from query3 q3)
```

select only the required columns in the super query

Comment: He doesn't need any `UNION` for that.

Comment: He needs the union becuase he wants to see the result for each question id in a particular manner...check he says he does not want 5,6,7,8,9..he wants 6,8,5,9,5...your or statement will bring the exact thing he does not want...

Comment: and that's why you use the `order by` ;) to put the results in that particular manner

Comment: Yes you have used this in this particular example...but if he needs any other orderings such as 11,6,10,5..then what do you suggest...he goes on modifying order by case...???

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS supports the `VALUES` constructor

```
SELECT questionid, secondquestionid
FROM   (VALUES(6,1), 
              (5, 2), 
              (10, 3), 
              (11, 4)) V(q, ord) 
       JOIN customquestionbank 
         ON q IN ( questionid, secondquestionid ) 
GROUP BY questionid, secondquestionid         
ORDER  BY MIN(ord)
```

Comment: In this case the order is correct but the info it's not. You need another join with this query to get the full info of the table.

Comment: @aF. - No. The OP just needs to add all additional columns to both the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`. As they haven't told us what they are I couldn't do that for them.

Answer (score 0):

if your RDBMS is `mysql`, I think you can try `ORDER BY FIELD` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customquestionbank
WHERE
  questionid IN(6, 5, 10, 11)
  OR secondquestionid IN(6, 5, 10, 11)
ORDER BY FIELD(questionid, 6) ASC
```

Comment: using field(), quite elegant, +1 from me :)

Comment: @tombom - Not valid in SQL Server and doesn't have the desired effect anyway (`secondquestionid` should not be ignored for sorting purposes when that is the matching column)

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, thanks for correcting. Somehow I thought this was about MySQL and adding a second sort criteria for secondquestionid is no big deal.

Comment: @tombom I can't see how this approach could be extended to do that. `secondquestionid` isn't necessarily of secondary importance to `questionid` for sorting. It just depends which column ends up matching so you couldn't just do `ORDER BY criteria1, criteria2`

Comment: @MartinSmith  Okay, okay, you are right. Didn't read the question attentive enough.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Union` with `Union ALL`

```
create table #t
(
    id int
)
insert into #t(id)values(5)
insert into #t(id)values(2)
insert into #t(id)values(4)
insert into #t(id)values(3)

Select * from
(
    Select * from #t where id = 5
    uNION All
    Select * from #t where id = 2
    uNION All
    Select * from #t where id = 4
    uNION All
    Select * from #t where id = 3
)K

DROP TABLE #t
```